# react font-awesome / icon is not clickable

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome-5

Trying to use FontAwesomeIcon wrapped in a button element.

Issue:
- Clicking on the icon itself does not trigger the button
- When adding text before the icon, clicking on the text triggers the button. But clicking the icon portion of the button still will not trigger.

```
<button className="profile-edit-btn">
     Edit <FontAwesomeIcon
        className="edit-icon"
        icon="edit"
        size="2x"
     />
</button>
```

[gif of clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXt0X.gif)

Any ideas why this is behaving this way?

Comment: it might helps, please check https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/310737/

Comment: Does font-awesome have a specific library for React, that you have used it as a component?